# makefile target command line

Tags: makefile, command-line, gnu-make, target

I'd like to use the first argument (target) of the make command as a value of a variable inside the `Makefile` so that instead of:

```bash
make var=arg1
```

I can do

```bash
make arg1
```

So that in the `Makefile` I can refer to it as `TARGET`:

```
$(TARGET): $(OBJS)
    @echo -e "\n\n\t\t*** Compiled $(TARGET) successfully! ***\n" ;
    $(FL) $(LFLAGS) -o $(BUILDS_DIR)$@ \
        $(OBJS) \
        $(LIBS)
    @echo -e "\n\n\t\t*** Linking $(TARGET) completed! ***\n"`
```

Additionally, is it possible to set `TARGET` to default value if make is called without an target argument?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using GNU make or some other make implementation?

Comment: yes GNU make. I forgot to say it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a list of all command line goals from `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` which is a list of all targets specified on the command line (you shouldn't make the assumption that there is only one of these though...).

Alternatively, you could use the `%` as follows:

```
%: $(OBJS)
    @echo making $@
    ...
```

Notice that this is a pattern rule with as long stem as possible, so it will only be executed if there is no other rule to service the command-line target (unless there is another %: rule, in which case it will only run the first).   If you make multiple targets, this will be run once per target.

Comment: it seems to work with $(MAKECMDGOALS). thanks a lot and sorry for the late reply (time zone issue). about the second option, I'd also thought of that but however I needed to set a variable TARGET and I didn't know how to do with that.